# Get real-time progress updates from a Python script in R

Tags: python, r, pipe, reticulate

I would like to get real-time progress updates from a Python script running in the background.

#### Python script

```py
from time import sleep
for i in range(10):
    print(f'file{i}.txt')
    sleep(1)
print('done')
```

I thought I could use a `pipe` connection but it appears that `readLines` doesn't return output until `my_script.py` is done running. How do I get real-time feedback from my Python job?

#### R script

```r
con <- pipe("python3 my_script.py")
while(TRUE) {
    files <- readLines(con) # waits for job to finish
    current_file <- tail(files, 1)
    if(current_file == "done") {
        print("Done processing files")
        break()
    } else {
        print(paste("Processing", current_file))
        Sys.sleep(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running your Python script unbuffered `con <- pipe("python3 -u my_script.py")`

Comment: `readLines` still waits for the script to finish running

Comment: I don't speak R. Does it have a simple `readline()` that reads a single line that you can put in a loop?

Comment: @MarkSetchell are you suggesting saving the Python status to a file on each loop?

Comment: I'm suggesting you read each line from the Python script immediately, as soon as it is output. I have no idea what the lines mean, or what you are trying to do with them. I'm merely saying if you try to read them all in one go, you will block until the process completes. And if you try to read them individually, one at a time, as they are output, you will need to unbuffer Python. That's all. HTH.